# slurm: write exit code or job status into logfile when finished (completed or failed)

Tags: exit-code, slurm

I need to make sure that all commands in my script finished successfully (returned 0 status). That's why my slurm script includes following lines:

```
set -e
set -x
```

Now I would like the exit status of the whole script to be written in the logfile that's automatically created by slurm. I have tried echo `$SLURM_JOB_EXIT_CODE` (with no success) or `echo $?` (which I am not sure is what I need) as a last line of my script.

What's the proper way to do this? I need to differentiate between "failed" and "completed" jobs, preferably by checking logfiles only.

Answer (score 2):

Catching the exit code of the script within the script is impossible so you should either

- wrap your script in another script that would take proper action based on its return code, or
- get the return code from Slurm's accounting with the `sacct` command.

Comment: "wrap your script in another script that would take proper action based on its return code" is very general, how to access the slrum EXIT code from another script ?

Comment: @BatiCode the idea is to run the script from another script that would the return code of the inner script ( which would be the return code Slurm exposes if it were not 'wrapped'), then take action, and exit with the same output as the inner script (for Slurm to capture it in accounting.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is my way of appending the final job status to the Slurm output.

```sh
res=$(sbatch job.sh)
echo $res
sleep 10s
ST="PENDING"
while [[ "$ST" != "COMPLETED" && "$ST" != "FAILED" ]] ; do
    ST=$(sacct -j ${res##* } -o State | awk 'FNR == 3 {print $1}')
    sleep 10s
done
echo "$ST" >> job.out # assuming stdout writes to job.out
```